# How to exclude certain index in a given query to see that index's impact

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2017

Lets say i have multiple indexes on a table

I want to exclude only 1 of them when executing the query

Lets say my indexes are named as `index_a`,`index_b`,`index_c`

The query is `select * from myTable where columnA='var1'`

So how can i exclude only `index_b` from this query?

The aim here is testing the impact of index. So I will run the query 2 times at the same query. At the first query i will have it with index enabled and in the second query i wont have it enabled. So the include actual execution plan will show me their relative to the batch query cost

I am giving example (real case is much more complex)

[image]

Comment: This request doesn't make sense.  Why would you want to exclude indexes?

Comment: [drop or disable it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? But this seems to be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), especially considering the query provided.

Comment: This could be useful to test the impact of dropping an index without actually dropping it.

Comment: To play devil's advocate - why does an index exist without a proven purpose? And dropping the index is the obvious path (at a certain cost), so the focus on one query alone and an attempt to "avoid" the index is very suspicious.

Comment: Ignore the given example queries here. The aim here is comparing impact of the index directly to without index. I have added a picture to illustrate question better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options:

- Index hints (Multiple index hints are a bad idea see [link](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/05/bad-idea-jeans-multiple-index-hints/))
- Disable index
- Drop index (won't recommend it for testing, could be a large table that takes some time to recreate the index)
- Copy the schema and data, except the index you want to exclude. (Less relevant, as statistics will be different for the newly created indexes)

#### Index hints

You could try executing the query with a specific index to test the difference:

```
select * 
from myTable WITH (INDEX(index_a)) -- or index_b or index_c
where columnA='var1'
```

Or with multiple hints:

```
select * 
from myTable WITH (INDEX(index_a, index_c)) -- Bad idea, only for testing.
where columnA='var1'
```

*You can also specify index hints on JOIN, see the documentation for [table hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) and [query hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-ver15)*

#### Disabled index

To disable an index:

```
ALTER INDEX index_b ON myTable   
DISABLE;
```

To enable an index see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/enable-indexes-and-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15#TsqlProcedure)

Comment: The aim here is testing the impact of index. So I will run the query 2 times at the same query. At the first query i will have it with index enabled and in the second query i wont have it enabled. So the include actual execution plan will show me their relative to the batch query cost

Comment: When testing queries (on a seperate environment) make sure you are testing against a clean environemnt. By clearing the cache, and enabling statistics to compare the right numbers.  Have a look at `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`and `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` to clear the caches. And `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` and `SET STATISTICS IO ON` to get the the actual times. Make sure you are also the only one active on the database, as you don't wont to test locking.

Comment: I have added a picture to illustrate better

Comment: Based on the picture, if you want to use Relative batch % cost to compare, you are limited to index hints, as ALTER INDEX will also receive a %. You are better of comparing I/O stats.

Comment: I see. So i have to type every index name to be able to compare. So no exclude hint available right?

Comment: Correct, you can only force a specific index to be used. There is no hint to exclude an index.